# Download a file from the depot

Tags: c#, perforce

```
P4Command cm = new P4Command(ps, "sync", true, String.Format("{0}/...", deppath));
P4CommandResult results = cm.Run();

if (results != null)
    Console.WriteLine("no problem");

TaggedObjectList listfiledown = new TaggedObjectList();
listfiledown = (results.TaggedOutput);

foreach (TaggedObject obj in listfiledown)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no problem");
}
```

I have to download a file from the depot to my workspace, so if  i run the command the taggedoutput is null , is there any solution for that?

> *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'*

Comment: Which line throws this exception? You can read [`What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: the taggedobjectlist is null so the exception was throwen in the the foreach

Comment: knowing that other commands works with files that are in my workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your command have returns a null `results.TaggedOutput`. I'd run under debugger, break after `cm.Run()`, and look at `results` to see whether it contains some kind of error description.

Failing that, check that your command is correct - for example, that `deppath` points to the correct path.